# How to share code between React Web and React Native applications?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, service

> Many thing like services and some code block in React JS and React
>   Native are common, so instead of write duplicate code I want to same
>   services for both React Js and React Native? Please suggested me, How
>   it can be possible.

Suppose here is 3 repository:

1) **ReactJs:** This repository is used for ReactJs application for Web development (ReactJS code is exist in this repository).

2) **ReactNative:** This repository is used for ReactNative application for Mobile development (ReactJS code is exist in this repository).

3) **ReactServices:** In this repository I have created some services which should be use in ReactJs and ReactNative

**For Example:** 
ReactServices: This repository with one service which name is data.service.js and in this one method and which name is getData

**File Name**: data.service.js

**Code:**

```
export const getData = () => {

    let data = {
        'name': 'sample name',
        'city': 'sample city'
    };
   return data;
}
```

**I want to use this service in both Project React Js and React Native, dont want to create individual services for both project**

**ReactJs:**

**FileName:** App.js

**Code:**

```
import * as datas from 'path../data.service';


datas.getData()
    .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(error => {

    });
}
```

**ReactNative:**
FileName: App.js
**Code:**

```
import * as datas from 'path../data.service';


datas.getData()
    .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(error => {

    });
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue ? If you are not using platform specific code / logic you are good to go !

Comment: Look into yarn workspaces: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

Comment: How can import from different repository, what will be path for this "import * as datas from 'path../data.service';"